# client/server connection closing causes loop error

Tags: java, android, sockets, client-server

I got to stage where client and server communicate, sending messages from and to each other.

The problem I am having is how to close the connection without causing an error?

If I terminate one of the apps (either server or client) that causes the connection to be lost, and then it causes the loop that is waiting for input to loop indefinitely and showing null's.

I tried closing sockets, buffers and even the thread, didn't work.

This is the client side

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
            new Thread(commThread).start();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
    }
}
```

This is the server side

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(
                        socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Both use these classes:

```
class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader input;
    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        try {
            this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                String read = input.readLine();
                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                //***HERE EXTRA BIT FOR THE SERVER


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private String msg;
    public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        text.setText(msg);
        }
}
```

the only difference is the server has this bit where it says above `***HERE EXTRA BIT FOR THE SERVER`

```
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println("Message recieved");
```

so basically, client connects, server accepts, then client sends message, servers receives message and shows it, and then sends "Message received" to the client, and the client shows it.

All this works fine, but once the connection is lost, they hang on showing null repeatedly, and I have to force the app to close.

Comment: do u want to keep the Connection on or Client call to Server everytime?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep the connection to send and recieve data, but I just want a solution for when the connection is lost, they don't hang on loop. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I just thought about it, I think I would need to close the connection, and the client connects every time it needs to do something. Thanks

Comment: my Suggestion to you is use : Client Side : AsyncTask which sends Data to the Server and Close the Connection by its own and lets you write code to the UI Thread if needed. i need to see the Logcat on either sides to see what is your null Exception and correct the problem

Comment: @Riverside assuming I can, then what to close?

Comment: @ItzikSamara the logcat doesn't show error, as if it is workig ok, and suppose to print out null

Comment: @Riverside That suggestion is nonsense. readLine() returns null, not "NULL", at end of stream. And it is checked with ==, not .equals(). And coded the way you suggest, you will lose every second line of input.

Comment: @Riverside That's right, shoot the messenger, don't address the issue. 'Nonsense' is an objective term in logic, and this is a branch of logic. Niceness has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking for end of stream. If readLine() returns null, the peer has closed the connection, and you must do likewise and stop reading.

It's hard to believe you really need a new thread for every line to update the UI.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried checking for null, didn't work, app collapses. How am I suppose to check for it? and what to do in case of finding null? Also, I didn't understand what do you mean by new thread for every line, is there a better way of doing this than having that many of threads?